# How to practise hinduism?

Tags: scripture, vedas, upanishads, practice, shaivism

How to practise Hinduism for a college student ?or how to practise Hinduism in general?Are there any benefits of it?
I am really confused on practising Hinduism? I am so much focused on my studies that I dont have that much time to understand Vedas or Upanishads , they are very complicated texts. Neither I am seeing god delivering knowledge. So what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Last but not the least,  *means(upaayam)* , one can practice /observe is suggested in Bhagavad Gita 9.27 and it's benefit is said in 9.28

> *yat karoṣhi yad aśhnāsi yaj juhoṣhi dadāsi yat
> yat tapasyasi kaunteya tat kuruṣhva mad-arpaṇam*
>
> **yat** whatever; **karoṣhi**—you do;  **aśhnāsi**—you eat;  **juhoṣhi**—offer  **dadāsi**—bestow as a gift; **tapasyasi**—austerities you perform; kaunteya—Arjun, the son of Kunti; **tat—them; kuruṣhva—do; mad arpaṇam—as an offering to Me**
> **Whatever you do, whatever you eat, whatever you offer , whatever you bestow as a gift, and whatever austerities you perform, O son of Kunti, do them as an offering to Me.**
> 9.27 Translation Swami Mukundananda

By dedicating all acts to the supreme lord , and through this steadfast remembrance with the spirit of consecration, love and devotion towards the supreme Ishwara, nothing seperate needs to be done, says 9.27..So there is no need to refrain from social duties/obligations.

> By dedicating all your works to Me, you will be freed from the bondage of good and bad results. With your mind attached to Me through renunciation, you will be liberated and will reach Me.
> Gita 9.28  Translation Swami Mukundananda

when every act is done as a service of supreme lord,one is freed from the bonds of action / ties of ego. otherwise these bonds would be the causative agent of future births (samsaara)

Gita 9.27 and 28 leads to the deliverance of Knowledge by the Supreme